# iOS basic FTP setup; Read and Write Stream

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ftp

I'm attempting to create an iOS 5 app with some very basic FTP functionality and need some guidance. It will be connecting to a device on a local network and performing read/write actions with .dat/txt files. I've done some searching for the past few days and have seen various recommendations but nothing simple enough that I can pick up and quickly modify for my personal use.

My questions are these:

1. Are there any tutorials/sample code that you could recommend to me?
2. What frameworks and classes should I be working with for basic read/write operations?

Lastly, I should mention that I have given a considerable amount of time to analyzing the SimpleFTPSample from Apple but the sample code is giving "Connection Failure" and "Stream Open Error" notices for each example, so I'm a bit wary of its usefulness.

Forgive me if this has been answered elsewhere. All of the related posts have pieces of the answer I need, but not the whole thing. Thank you in advance!

EDIT for clarity: A well-defined example or step-by-step tutorial is what I would really like. My own Google searches have turned up nothing and I am desperately in need of some guidance here.

**UPDATE:**
I posted this question long ago but have continued using the FTPHelper mentioned in the accepted answer. I recently brushed the dust off the old project and realized there was a minor memory leak in FTPHelper's fetch function that can be an app-killer if called repeatedly. If anybdy stumbles across this question and chooses to use FTPHelper, be sure to add the CFRelease line seen in the code below.

```
- (void) fetch: (NSString *) anItem
{
    if (!self.uname || !self.pword) COMPLAIN_AND_BAIL(@"Please set user name and password first");
    if (!self.urlString) COMPLAIN_AND_BAIL(@"Please set URL string first");

    NSString *ftpRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", self.urlString, [anItem stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
/*  CFShow(ftpRequest); */
    NSString *writepath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    self.filePath = [writepath stringByAppendingPathComponent:anItem];
    CFURLRef writeURL = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation (NULL, (const UInt8 *) [writepath UTF8String], [writepath length], NO); 
    MySimpleDownload((CFStringRef)ftpRequest, writeURL, (CFStringRef) self.uname, (CFStringRef)self.pword);
    CFRelease(writeURL);//ADD THIS LINE TO FIX MEMORY LEAK 
}
```

Comment: can you send code source code how to implement ftp for download file without internet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SimpleFTPSample app is running perfect, probably there is an issue that you can't see. What I can recommend you (except Apple's example) is to check [THIS](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/15-FTP%20Helper) example which contains a helper class for all basic FTP operations. One thing to be aware of is iOS 5 ARC. Both Apple's example and the one I linked are for older iOS versions.

There are basically 2 ways to use them in iOS 5 - by telling the compiler to not use ARC by adding `-fno-objc-arc` flag in [Your project] -> TARGETS -> [Your app] -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> [Your file], or by using the built-in tool in Xcode for converting to ARC.

I personally have tested only the first method and it works for me.

If this does not help you I can write an example, but unfortunately today I am very busy.

UPDATED:

The basic mechanism is to use `[FTPHelper list:THE_FTP_URL]` to list the content of a folder, then create one list with the content and depending on the type (file or folder) download using `[FTPHelper download: THE_FTP_URL_WITH_THE_FILENAME_FROM_LISTING]`. From here you have to implement

```
- (void) downloadFinished
{
    //do the reading depending on the file type
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[FTPHelper sharedInstance].filePath];
}
```

The uploading is achieved in a similar way - using `[FTPHelper upload:FILE_TO_UPLOAD]` with a file from the filesystem.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what I'm doing wrong with SimpleFTP. Regardless, thank you for the other example. I'm tinkering around with it right now and it's already giving results (a nice change of pace!). Assuming you are familiar with the FTPHelper class, how would you recommend downloading foo.txt and reading its contents? Or how about writing content to foo2.txt and uploading it?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can check it. If something is not clear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Great. What a relief it is to finally have something to work with. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad I could help. Just have in mind it is too much work if you want to build a completely reliable FTP client with start/pause, handling network connection loss and other issues. That's why you can have a look also at the ready libraries that Dominik Hadl suggested.

Comment: How to download entire folder ? I am using                   [FTPHelper download:@"FolderName"]; it is just downloading zero byte. Thanks

Comment: You cannot "download" a folder, what you have to do is list all files from the folder and download each file. If there are subfolders inside, you have to do the same for them. On the device side, when saving the files on the File System, recreate the folder structure from the file path. Read my answer once again and I think you will get the mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

There are many libraries which you could use and they are working great. :)

For example:

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-objc.asp

http://code.google.com/p/ios-ftp-server/

I recommend using them, because coding one by yourself would take a lot of time :)
One thing to remember, as o15a3d4l11s2 said, is to be aware of ARC. If you use it don't forget to add build flags to libraries which aren't ARC.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative libraries. I think I may stick with the FTPHelper but these things tend to require backup plans so these are great to have.

Comment: i need to make an app which supports to upload larger videos even if the app is in the background can  i use this  
There are many libraries which you could use and they are working great. :)

For example:

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-objc.asp ??