# read/write text to the textFile through the internet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm new in Objective C programming and I need some help in read/write to the files.

I have a text file at my FTP - ftp://www.abc.com/A.txt which has full access on all. I want to read and write text in it.

Thanks for any help
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either...

1. Download A.txt from the server and store locally.
2. Append new line/s to an existing text file.
3. Save it and upload that document to ftp.

Or...

This may help you...[iOS basic FTP setup; Read and Write Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704225/790794)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's really good way but I am oriented to speed and want to edit the file.
Also I need this code for my iPhone Application.
Thanks again.