# iOS simple ftp file upload not works

Tags: ios, ftp

I used SimpleFTPSample => result "stream open error"

I used whiteRaccoon => result "unknown error"

I used BlackRaccoon => result "File or directory not available or directory already exists." or "Unknown FTP error!"

setProperties => url, UserName, Password, Port, PassiveMode

it works my android app =>ftp://***.***.**.***:****

```
url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] smartURLForString:@"ftp://***.**.***.***:****"];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS basic FTP setup; Read and Write Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672617/ios-basic-ftp-setup-read-and-write-stream)

Comment: no its not duplicate